# Кинологическая терминология

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишутся слова: "Апорт!", апортировка, апортировочный предмет - с одной или двумя буквами п?

Comment: Почему не обратится к словарю? Так быстрее будет и тише.

Answer (score 1):

С одним. Всегда.

Апорт (команда) при дрессировке собак.
Апорт (поисковая система) — российский интернет-магазин (ранее — поисковая система).
Апорт (сорт яблок) — алматинский сорт яблок.
Апорт (операция) — советская крупная военная операция по обнаружению стратегических подводных лодок США, проведённая в 1985 году.
Апорт (имущество) — имущество, поступающее акционерному обществу в уплату за акции предприятия.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82